# The program shown over uses the Pthreads API. What would be the output from the program at LINE C and LINE P?

Tags: c, process, pthreads, fork, posix

```
int value = 0;
void *runner(void *param); /* the thread */

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pid_t pid;
    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_attr_t attr;

    pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0)  /* child process */
    { 
        pthread_attr_init(&attr);
        pthread_create(&tid,&attr,runner,NULL);
        pthread_join(tid,NULL);
        printf("CHILD: value = %d\n",value); /* LINE C */
    } 
    else if (pid > 0)  /* parent process */
    {
         wait(NULL);
         printf("PARENT: value = %d\n",value); /* LINE P */
    }
}

void* runner(void* param) 
{ 
    value = 5;
    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Is the value at LINE C = 5 and at LINE P = 0. But why is this? I'm thinking it's because the child process is a copy of the parent process but anything that changes in the child process doesn't necessarily change in the parent process.

In the child process the runner thread is invoked and this thread changes the value to 5 and then prints it out.

When the child is finished the parent process then prints out 0 because no operations were performed on this value. Is this correct?

Comment: yes, with `fork()` the child process receive an exact copy of the parent memory

Answer (score 3):

The only time that a child process writing to memory also makes changes in the parent process's memory is when the memory written to is explicitly shared memory.  The `value` variable is a regular variable (not in shared memory).  Nothing the child does to its copy of the variable does anything to the parent's copy.  On the other hand, threads do share the same memory space, so the thread in the child modifies the memory that the child's main thread has access to.

Be aware that when a process forks, the child process has only a single thread, even if the parent was multithreaded.  It isn't a factor in this question (the use of threads is essentially tangential to the result obtained), but it would not be hard to modify the code so that it did become an issue.